# Can Black draw this game?

Tags: endgame, draw, blitz, carlsen, rook-and-minor-endgame

Carlsen-Svidler 2010 Blitz. Black to move. Can he draw by perpetual checks? In the actual game, he resigned two moves later.

```
[FEN "6R1/8/3B4/5K1k/r7/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perpetual check is out of the question (after Ra5+ Be5 the only check is Rxe5+ but that loses quickly) but this endgame has some other drawing techniques: stalemate and exchanging rooks. However, according to [endgame databases](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=6R1/8/3B4/5K1k/r7/8/8/8_b_-_-_0_1) Black is losing (their rook) in 13 moves and will be mated shortly after. It is very reminiscent of the [Philidor position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_and_bishop_versus_rook_endgame#Philidor_position), especially after the 2nd move by White listed there. The white pieces dominate the Black rook and it is soon out of tricks.

Comment: What about Ra5+ 2.Be5 Ra6 Now if bishop moves he can check again, and also if king moves. If 3.Ra1 then Ra4

Comment: 3. Rg3; you can perform the moves in the endgame database I linked to, and it will tell you the best moves for White.